# How to pack widgets in a gtk_dialog window using gtk3

Tags: c, gtk3, gtk2

In **gtk2** the following code snippet works to pack widgets into a **gtk_dialog** window, using the **vbox** and **action_area** of the **GtkDialog** structure:

```
  window=gtk_dialog_new();
  gtk_container_set_border_width((GtkContainer *)window, 0);

  scrolled_window=gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL,NULL);
  gtk_container_set_border_width((GtkContainer *)scrolled_window, 10);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_shadow_type((GtkScrolledWindow *)scrolled_window, GTK_SHADOW_IN);
  gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy((GtkScrolledWindow *)scrolled_window, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

  gtk_box_pack_start((GtkBox *) (GtkDialog *)window->vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_widget_show(scrolled_window);

  label=gtk_label_new(text);
  gtk_label_set_use_markup((GtkLabel *)label, TRUE);

  gtk_label_set_selectable((GtkLabel *)label, TRUE);
  gtk_label_set_line_wrap((GtkLabel *)label, FALSE);
  gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport((GtkScrolledWindow *)scrolled_window, label);
  gtk_widget_show(label);

  button=gtk_button_new_with_label("close");
  g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);

  gtk_widget_set_can_default(button, TRUE);
  gtk_box_pack_start((GtkBox *) (GtkDialog *)window->action_area), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  gtk_widget_grab_default(button);
  gtk_widget_show (button);

  gtk_widget_show(window);
```

However in **gtk3** this is not completely valid code any more. And it will not compile.

If I replace instances of:

```
(GtkBox *) (GtkDialog *)window->vbox
```

with:

```
(GtkBox *) (GtkDialog *)window
```

And do the same with instances of action_area the code will compile but the window will not show the extra packed widgets, just the ones the dialog comes with by default.

More information, which to me is a bit contradictory https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-struct

> The GtkDialog contains only private fields and should not be directly
>   accessed.

But when I read this on the same page it seems to contradict the previous quote https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-add-action-widget

> If you want to add a non-activatable widget, simply pack it into the
>   action_area field of the GtkDialog struct.

Earlier in that document it states under ***GtkDialog as GtkBuildable***

> The GtkDialog implementation of the GtkBuildable interface exposes the
>   vbox and action_area as internal children with the names “vbox” and
>   “action_area”.

But I don't really know how to do that using the *GtkBuildable interface* neither do I want to. Or perhaps that is exactly what I did in gtk2 and it stopped working in gtk3...?

My question is how can I convert the gtk2 code to work with gtk3 with as few changes as possible. I have been searching for quite a while but found no answer yet. The existing gtk3 documentation leaves me going in circles. Maybe I just miss something totally obvious. Or perhaps you are not supposed to do this anymore and have to use a window instead of a dialog?

Thanks to the answer below I was able to change the code to this working one, it will also eliminate a deprecated warning about **gtk_dialog_get_action_area()** by using **gtk_dialog_add_button()**

```
window=gtk_dialog_new();
gtk_container_set_border_width((GtkContainer *)window, 0);

scrolled_window=gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL,NULL);
gtk_container_set_border_width((GtkContainer *)scrolled_window, 10);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_shadow_type((GtkScrolledWindow *)scrolled_window, GTK_SHADOW_IN);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy((GtkScrolledWindow *)scrolled_window, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

gtk_box_pack_start((GtkBox *) (GtkDialog *) (gtk_dialog_get_content_area(window)), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_widget_show(scrolled_window);

label=gtk_label_new(text);
gtk_label_set_use_markup((GtkLabel *)label, TRUE);

gtk_label_set_selectable((GtkLabel *)label, TRUE);
gtk_label_set_line_wrap((GtkLabel *)label, FALSE);
gtk_container_add((GtkContainer *)scrolled_window, label);
gtk_widget_show(label);

button=gtk_dialog_add_button((GtkDialog *)window, "close", GTK_RESPONSE_CLOSE);
g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "response", (GCallback *)gtk_widget_destroy, window);

gtk_widget_set_can_default(button, TRUE);  
gtk_widget_grab_default(button);

gtk_widget_show(button); 
gtk_widget_show(window);

gtk_dialog_run((GtkDialog*)window);
gtk_widget_destroy(window);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the top section you `gtk_dialog_get_content_area`. This will return a VBox, where you can pack your own widgets.

For the bottom section you either `gtk_dialog_add_button` or `gtk_dialog_add_action_widget`.

---

> The GtkDialog contains only private fields and should not be directly accessed.
>
> If you want to add a non-activatable widget, simply pack it into the action_area field of the GtkDialog struct.

You should obtain a pointer to action_area with deprecated (!)`gtk_dialog_get_action_area`, but that will not allow to register a response id.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. Both using the deprecated one and gtk_dialog_get_action_area with regards to the button.

Comment: @aseq avoid using deprecated methods to make future translation to gtk4 easier

Comment: Yes I know, but  eliminating deprecated stuff is the easier step. Also something which is deprecated in, say, gtk3, is guaranteed to at least be available in gtk3, albeit with compilation warnings. Typically I eliminate all deprecated stuff and migrate  once the DE I make the application for migrates to a newer gtk major version. Problem is often deprecations happen half way through gtk's major version release cycle, very annoying. For example gtk_dialog_get_action_area() deprecated since 3.12.